# Formatting Bug with superscripted text being ignored?

Tags: support, formatting

in a [recent answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/revisions/191424/3), I used the following (simplified) code snippet:

```
[cleartext argumentation] <sup>4, 6, 8</sup>

> [Blockquote from source] <sup>6</sup>
```

However, for some reason it parses into

> In later generations, the outspoken rule becomes that only at
> character generation one can obtain rites with background or freebie
> points, in 1st edition that is only implicit. <sup>4, 6, 8</sup>
>
> > Subsequently [to character generation], however, rites can be learned only through roleplaying; they may not be purchased with
> > experience points. 6

and the command console makes it evident, that the second set of superscripted text in the quoted area is seemingly ignored:

[image: photo of the command prompt that leads to the parsed text above]

In a similar fashion, another section of superscripted text after the blockquote is likewise just normalized.

However, for some *odd* reason, the very same snippet of code does work *here* on the meta... did I type some strange extra character in there that got lost in copying or something?!

### investigation

Adding another `<sup></sup>` to turn it into `<sup>6</sup><sup></sup>` does make the first 6 into superscripted text, but this does not work for the second instance of non-parsed superscript text - there `<sup>4, 6, 8</sup><sup></sup><sup></sup>` was needed to display as superscripted text.

Apparently, just having the latter code bit *also* somehow fixes the first formatting issue.

Also, closing each portion of superscripted text does seems to *fix* the issue. `<sup>6</sup></sup>`

Comment: It seems like you just forgot to close a sup tag

Comment: @Medix2 yes... one I did *not* look at.

Comment: @doppel I'm really not sure code formatting is a great idea here but I'm not sure of a good alternative.  It's a lot of actual text in there

Comment: @Medix2 it can be helped... let me try something

Comment: We're trying to show the plaintext version of markdown, that's entirely what a code block is for. There was already sufficient word wrap that both sups are in view.

Comment: though the text can be *cut* in the top example, cleaning up the apparent problem area. not entirely sure which solution look cleaner

Comment: @doppel Then I guess mobile uses different formatting since it didn't wrap at all but had a scrollbar due to the lengthier lines

Comment: @Medix2 it had 3 lines and 2 lines, but wasn't really "mobile friendly" as mobile only has much less of a column width.

Comment: @Medix2 Oh, no, I mean there were already word breaks in those lines. Desktop doesn't word wrap either.

Comment: Is the text in the question that is supposed to be in error written correctly? All of your sup tags are correct...

Comment: @ThomasMarkov read the answer: one was off.

Comment: Ah, so you typed it wrong in your original post, then typed it right in the question here?

Comment: @ThomasMarko yes and no: if you look at the linked old version, it was a line *before* the quoted part, that resulted in the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm a doofus!

a preceding line read

```
There is a roll and time spent with the teacher, that's it. <sup>2, 4, 6, 8<sup>
```

Of course with no closed supertext, all kinds of errors are to be expected... The fix was therefore adding the needed `/`:

```
There is a roll and time spent with the teacher, that's it. <sup>2, 4, 6, 8</sup>
```

Why it did not err out on the very next but only the one after that I fail to understand, but might be an interaction between the supertext and blockquote tag.